# Is it a better practice to use Postgres default value or generate them before passing to Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

Is it a better practice to use Postgres default value or generate them before passing to Postgres?

For example, is it better to use DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in Postgres or is it better to get current time on server and then pass to Postgres?

Comment: I'll go with `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as you may face some time zone / format mess up when you send the time by yourself. But I don't think it'll really change anything else...

Comment: I don't think there is a "better practice", it depends on your use case. DEFAULT can be handy, but it's not always what you want. Like your application might want to insert another timestamp.

Comment: @A.Scherbaum Same time

Answer (score 0):

I would say to go with `DEFAULT`.

At least you have a backup value if, for whatever reason, you don't pass or forget to pass in anything to the database.

Moreover, when you pass around data between back-end and front-end which you believe is of a certain type (for example, a string or `TEXT` in Postgres) when in reality it is `NULL` this may very well lead to the client app throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a default value for all columns then you can always assume to have at least this value present when you query data from this table. This is particularly interesting when you are working with strings and want to check e.g. the length of a bio in a profile. You can skip any null check completely and possibly avoid exceptions.